# wrong value shown in explorer.io

Tags: myetherwallet

I´ve bought GAME (GTC) and transferred it to My Ether Wallet. It shows me the amount of GTC, but the value shown in USD is not correct. How is that possible?

Thank You

Comment: Prices can fluctuate. Markets can trade at different prices. What value are you expecting to see?

Comment: Approximately 110 USD should be correct. But only 5 USD are shown. I have about 400 GTC

Comment: Interesting. What's the address you've sent them to?